# I cannot find data JSON file to use ImportJSON in google sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I want to parse the data on google sheets. 
The link is here: https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/apple/balance-sheet

But I cannot find the data JSON file in this link.
Where can I find the data in this link?

or How can I parse the data on google sheets using ImportJSON?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I want to parse the data on google sheets.`, I cannot understand about the result you expect. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I mean, I want to import the data of table in my link on google sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that you want to put the table of the URL to Google Spreadsheet. In this case, how about achieving your goal using Google Apps Script? Because in the URL, the table is created by Javascript. So the table cannot be directly retrieved by importJson and the built-in functions of Spreadsheet. How about this?

Comment: Thank you for your replying. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use Google Apps Script and how to achieve my goal using it. Where can I learn the Google Apps Script or How can I achieve my goal using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to answer about your 2 question. A1. About Google Apps Script, you can see several documents at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info). A2. I think that in this case, how about this flow? 1. Retrieve the HTML data. 2. Retrieve and parse the values from HTML data. 3. Put the values to Spreadsheet. I think that [these threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+scraping) might be useful.